# Is eclipse plugin for hadoop work with CDH3

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop, cloudera

I install the cloudera CDH3 on my machine. Then I try to use eclipse plugin (JIRA MAPREDUCE-1280) to do some MR tasks. However, it seems like the plugin not work with CDH3 for some reason. It cannot connect to the DFS.

Does any get the plugin working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDH3 is incompatible to Apache Hadoop 0.20.2.
The Eclipse-Plugin from JIRA MAPREDUCE-1280 is built against Apache Hadoop.
It is not compatible with CDH3.